# I can't figure out how to edit array items using a map function in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

So I have been trying for days to solve the following issue:

```
movies [
{
     id: 1,
     name: 'Alpha',
     rating: 0
},
{
     id: 2,
     name: 'Bravo',
     rating: 0
},
{
     id: 3,
     name: 'Charlie',
     rating: 0
}
]
```

I already have a way to add and delete movies to/from this array but I want to have an input section for each item where the rating state will be updated to the input's value. I have been using 'useReducer' to assist with this but I guess I'm just not sure of the syntax/what would be the payload?

I know there is a way to do movies.map(movie=> {etc.etc.} but I can't seem to figure it out. Help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<div>
{movies.map(movie => (
    <h1>{movie.name}</h1>
    <input placeholder={movie.rating}
    onChange={//I WANT THE MOVIE.RATING TO CHANGE ON INPUT CHANGE//}
    />
))}
</div>
```

I want the output to look something like this, where the state of the {movie.rating} object is updated on input change

Comment: Please, post the desired output

Comment: ```
<div>
{movies.map(movie => (
 <h1>{movie.name}</h1>
 <input placeholder={movie.rating}
 onChange={//I WANT THE MOVIE.RATING TO CHANGE ON INPUT CHANGE//}
 />
))}
</div>
```

Something like this, where the state of the movie.rating object is updated on input change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using movies as component state you can pass this to your `onChange` function:

```
const updateRatingOnly = (id,rating) => {
    movies = movies.map(movie => {
      if(movie.id === id){
       return{...movie, rating}
      }
      return movie
    })

   setMovies(movies)

   //or

   this.setState({movies})
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a bunch! I ended up getting it to work by altering the code slightly
```
const handleRatingChange = (e, rating, id) => {
    setMovies(movies.map(movie => {
      if(movie.id === id) {
        return {...movie, rating: e.target.value}
      }
      return movie
    }))
    console.log(movies,rating,id)
  }

```

Thank you for the assistance though!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by chaining the functions with the event. So your event handler will look like this:

```js
const handleRatingChange = (movie) => ({target: {value}) => {
  //useReducer logic
  //movie = movie name
  //value = new rating
};
```

```html
<div>
{movies.map(movie => (
    <h1>{movie.name}</h1>
    <input placeholder={movie.rating}
    onChange={handleRatingChange(movie.name)}
    />
))}
</div>
```